# echo complex text to a file

Tags: batch-file

Hi 
How to echo "LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)# 12M #ifeq $(TARGET_PRODUCT),sometext)PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \" to a file? I need the whole thing without quotes.

This is batch file on Windows7 by the way.

Thanks
SSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A safe way is to use the delayed expansion `!` instead of `%`.

In your example it would also work with `%`, but in the most cases, the delayed expansion is better, as the expanded content is not parsed anymore.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)# 12M #ifeq $(TARGET_PRODUCT),sometext)PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \"
>output.txt echo !var!
```